# Passing redux state to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to delete an element from dom by clicking on it. I did it without the problem without redux thunk but now I have a problem. My reducer doesn't know about the state. How do let him know what items are?

Action:

```
export function deleteItem(index) {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_ITEM',
        index
    };
}
```

My reducer that shows undefined.

```
export function deleteItem(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE_ITEM':
            const copy = state.items.slice()
            console.log(copy)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Heres my actual code https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/flashcards/tree/develop/src

Comment: Is deleteItem being triggered? I think the problem isn't on the code listed above.

Comment: Action is triggered. It is passing index. The problem is with reducer and him not knowing about actual state of app(state.items)

Comment: Why do you want to delete it from `store` itself? You can remove it from your component state. Why want to remove from `store`?

Comment: Whats the proper way of doing it?

Comment: @Abinthaha : If the items should be used from the store, shouldn't they also be removed from the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indicate the initial State of the reducer by default , the state is an empty array and you can't access the state.items , cause it is undefined. Assume this:

```
const x = [];
x.foo.slice();
```

that would return an error . Thus from :

```
state = []
```

change it to :

```
state = {
     items:[]
}
```

applying it to your code:

```
export function deleteItem(   
state = {
     items:[]
}, 
action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE_ITEM':
            const copy = state.items.slice()
            console.log(copy)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: items array is filled with api data with componentdidmount, i want to access this array

Comment: The Reducer who holds the whole array should also be connected to the reducer that manipulates the array itself. If it is not connected then You need to pass in the whole array to the function.

Comment: I know whats wrong, but i dont know how to fix it. How to pass items filled with api data to that reducers state?

Comment: Have you tried logging the state? try console.log(state) and see what is inside

Answer (score 1):

I saw your code and you are defining a new reducer for each of the operations you want to get done to your items (e.i  itemsHaveError, deleteItem, ...) but the correct way of doing this is to store all of the relevant functions for the items to a single reducer which holds the data needed to change whenever some action to the items happens, but in the way you did it, any time any action happens because your reducers are separated the initial state gets empty as you have passed to the functions and the reducers do not know about their related data so they overwrite them with the empty initial state, the correct way would be like this to write a single reducer for items:

```
    const initialState = {
      isLoading: false,
      hasError: false,
      items: [],
    };

    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ITEMS_HAVE_ERROR:
          return {
            ...state,
            hasError: action.hasError,
          };
        case ITEMS_ARE_LOADING:
          return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: action.isLoading,
          };
        case ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            items: action.items,
          };
        case DELETE_ITEM:
          const copy = state.items.slice()
          return {
            ...state,
            items: copy,
          };      
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

so this would be your item.js and your item reducer and the only one that should get to combineReducer function.

Comment: And now i have error: 
No reducer provided for key "reducer"
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers

"Reducer" is mainreducer that is passed to combinereducers, whats wrong? Thanks for reply.

Comment: can I see your reducer file and your index.js  after the changes?

Comment: As a guess, I think from your index.js you are importing the reducer like import {items} from './items' but in the code above I have used export default function so you should import it like: import items from './items' not like {items}